# mptt TreeNodeChoiceField filtered

Tags: django, mptt

I am starting to work with django.
In my project I am using MPTT.

I have a fairly simple models.

- Category: (the tree)
- Product1: a reference and a foreign key to the category.

I added the root to the Category model, just to simplify the search for the base category for one specific product

models.py

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    @property
    def root(self):
      return self.get_root().name

class Product1(models.Model):
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True) #YVX2311
    category = TreeForeignKey(Category)
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Category, MPTTModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Product)
```

What I would like is to modify the admin form, to be able to say something like.

> models.ForeignKey(Category, limit_choices_to = {root : 'Some
>   Category for products1'})

Of course this is not possible, but it does illustrate what I want.

I want to be able to filter the TreeChoiseField to show only some branches based on a property on the model (root in this case).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After much scrambling, I found a solution.
I do not think this is the best way to do it, but as far as I can see, it works.

I overloaded the mptt TreeNodeChoiceField and copied the TreeForeignKeyFiltered

In products, I changed the foreingkey for

> category = TreeForeignKeyFiltered(Category, root = 'MotherBoard')

I added the root keyword to the TreeForeingKeyFiltered

```
class TreeForeignKeyFiltered(models.ForeignKey):
    """
    Extends the foreign key, but uses mptt's ``TreeNodeChoiceField`` as
    the default form field.

    This is useful if you are creating models that need automatically
    generated ModelForms to use the correct widgets.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._root = kwargs.pop('root', None)
        super(TreeForeignKeyFiltered, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Use MPTT's ``TreeNodeChoiceField``
        """
        kwargs.setdefault('root', self._root)
        kwargs.setdefault('form_class', TreeNodeChoiceFieldFiltered)
        return super(TreeForeignKeyFiltered, self).formfield(**kwargs)
```

And finally I added the TreeNodeChoiceFieldFiltered as

```
class TreeNodeChoiceFieldFiltered(TreeNodeChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
        _root = kwargs.pop('root', None)

        if _root is not None:
            pid = None
            for i in queryset:
                if i.root.name == _root:
                    pid = i.tree_id
                    break

            if pid is not None:
                queryset = queryset.filter(tree_id = pid) 

        super(TreeNodeChoiceFieldFiltered, self).__init__(queryset, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now I can pass a keyword root to the foreingkey that will filter the posibilities in the admin form.

Again, I do not know if this is the best way to do it. Of course it can be cleaner....